# Displaying RMSE in summary when running multiple univariate linear regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression

I wrote a function to run univariate linear regressions for multiple variables at a time. However, in the summary table, I noticed that the RMSE is missing. How do I also display the RMSE to each of these regressions?

Here is my code and here is what my output looks like:

```
my.data <- read.csv("filename.csv", header=TRUE)

variables <-names(my.data[1:30])
my.list <- lapply(variables, function(var){formula <- as.formula(paste("gene ~", var))
res.linear <- lm(formula, data = my.data)
summary(res.linear)
})
lapply(my.list, coefficients)
```

---

```
[[1]]
                  Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   23.367075060 4.46417498 5.2343547 3.017975e-06
variable1     0.008312962 0.04747918 0.1750865 8.616917e-01

[[2]]
                 Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   5.347246142 1.48314397 3.605345 0.0006984638
variable2     0.008342116 0.01577413 0.528848 0.5991611451
```

Answer (score 0):

We may extract the `residuals` from the summary output, get the squared `mean` and take the square root and `cbind` with the extracted `coef`ficients

```
my.list <- lapply(variables, function(var){
   formula <- as.formula(paste("gene ~", var))
    res.linear <- lm(formula, data = my.data)
    smry <- summary(res.linear)
    RMSE <- sqrt(mean(smry$residuals^2))
    cbind(coef(smry), RMSE = RMSE)
      })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I really appreciate it. I tried your code but got the following error:  "Error in object$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @LilyL You don't need the second lapply.  Please check the output from `my.list` i.e. what you are doing in the last line `lapply(my.list, coefficients)` is already extracted in the first lapply